# Assigning values to array - Assembly

Tags: arrays, assembly

I am trying to read chars from input file, and place them in an array (except new line chars).

here is my code:

```
    mov dword [counter], 0
    mov edi, [size]
loop:   
    mov esi, state
    cmp [counter], edi  ; read all chars of the file
    je end_loop
    pushad
    mov eax, 3
    mov ebx, dword [file_desc]
    mov ecx, read_char
    mov edx, 1
    int 0x80
    popad

    cmp byte [read_char], '1'
    je put_char
    cmp byte [read_char], ' '
    je put_char
    jmp loop

put_char:
    mov edx, [read_char]
    mov [esi + counter], edx

    ;; print number of char read from 0 to size-1
    pushad
mov ecx, dword [counter]
push ecx
push printInt
call printf
add esp, 8
popad

;; print char read
    pushad
    push edx
    push printChar
    call printf
    add esp, 8
    popad

    ;; print value stored in state[counter]
    pushad
    push dword [esi + counter]
    push printChar
    call printf
    add esp, 8
    popad

    mov eax, [counter]
    inc eax
    mov [counter], eax

    jmp loop
end_loop:
```

the printing inside the loop works fine, as i get the char number, the char i have just read and the char in [esi + counter] (supposed to be state[counter]).

however, trying to print it after the reading loop, with this code:

```
    mov dword [counter], 0
    mov edi, [size]
printarray:
    mov esi, state
    cmp [counter], edi
    je end

    pushad
    push dword [esi + counter]
    push printChar
    call printf
    add esp, 8
    popad

    pushad
    mov ecx, [counter]
    inc ecx
    mov [counter], ecx
    popad
    jmp printarray
end:
```

all I get is blanks (new char lines every line, from my printChar).

I don't understand my the values I read are not stored in the array.
There is no code between `end loop` and `mov dword [counter], 0` just before the `printarray` loop.

mere are my data and bss:

```
section .data
newLine:    DB "", 10, 0
printInt:   DB "%d", 10, 0
printString:    DB "%s", 10, 0
printChar:  DB "%c", 10, 0
hello:      DB "hello", 10, 0

section .bss
file_name resb 80
file_desc resd 1
WorldLength resd 1
WorldWidth resd 1
generations resd 1
print_freq resd 1
state resb 60*60
read_char resb 1
counter resd 1
size resd 1
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Well...

First of all, don't use 32-bit registers when operating on bytes. I'm sure that even if your code worked, some data would be overwritten.

I believe that your problem resides somewhere in statements similar to these

```
mov [esi + counter], edx
...
push dword [esi + counter]
```

They actually mean: "take the address of counter and add it to esi", which I think isn't what you want.

Onto this, 
 - reading the file character by character is terribly inefficient
 - using counter variables instead of ecx is inefficient
 - incrementing register rather than a memory location iself is inefficient too

I've tried to rewrite your code as much as I could, and I hope it was worth something.

```
mov eax, 3
mov ebx, dword [file_desc]
mov ecx, state
mov edx, [size]
int 0x80
; eax now contains the number of bytes read, so why not to use it?

mov ebx, eax
add ebx, state
mov byte [ebx], 0x0 ; this will be end-of-string, although it may not really be necessary

xor ecx, ecx    ; this will be our counter now
_loop:          ; loop is actually an instruction
    cmp ecx, eax
    je _end
    inc ecx     ; ecx++

    mov dl, '\n'
    cmp byte [state + ecx], dl      ; is newline?
    jne _loop                       ; nope? ok, try again

    mov dl, ' '                     ; yes?
    mov byte [state + ecx], dl      ; replace newline with space character
    jmp _loop
_end:

; print the result
mov edx, eax    ; the size - number of bytes read
mov eax, 4
mov ebx, dword [file_desc]
mov ecx, state
int 0x80
```

Comment: why if the byte isn't new line i should jump back to the loop? these are the chars i want to read. also, i know the file only contains spaces, ones and new lines chars.
i'll try this though, thanks

Comment: btw, the size is not how many to read, but how many to write, does it make a difference?

Comment: You write out only those you've read in, for the code above only replaces the newlines with spaces.

Comment: what about ones? as i need to read those to. my input file is sort of a 2D array of ones and spaces that i need to place in "state"

Comment: and the size is the length*width of that 2D array, so the file contains more than size characters

Comment: about replacing the newlines with spaces, i dont want anything instead of them, i need to ignore them completely

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.
I should have used this to put the char in the array:

```
put_char:
mov dl, [read_char]
mov [esi], dl

mov eax, [counter]
inc eax
mov [counter], eax
inc esi

jmp loop
```

I removed the printing, those were for debugging only.

Thanks :)

Comment: Anyway, remember that you may use `inc dword [counter]` directly.